# awk + paste for cleaning up PATH?

Tags: text-processing, awk, path, tcsh

I have seen this code in `.cshrc` init files on a few machines. I went through [a few awk  tutorials](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/) in trying to understand how it works, but I am still unable to decrypt it.

```
setenv PATH `echo $PATH | awk 'NF&&\\!x[$0]++' RS='[:|\n]' | paste -sd:`
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't work for me with the backslashes but I can explain this one to you:

```
echo "$PATH" | awk 'NF && !x[$0]++' RS='[:|\n]'
```

The record separator (`RS`) is set to one of the characters ":", "|" and newline. `$PATH` is usually just one line with elements separated by ":". This makes awk behave like the paths were not separated by ":" but each on its own line.

`NF` means that empty lines (`NF == 0`) are ignored. `x` is an associative array with the paths as subscript. `!x[$0]++` means that the "line" is ignored if `x[$0]` is greater than 0. The result is that every line is output just once. During the first run `x[$0]` is increased so that in the following runs `!x[$0]` is false.

This example shows the frequency of all elements after the last line has been processed:

```
echo "a:b:a:c:a:b" |
  awk 'NF && !x[$0]++;END {for (var in x) print var ": " x[var]}' RS='[:|\n]'
a
b
c
a: 3
b: 2
c: 1
```

Comment: I just checked with OpenBSD awk (nawk) and gawk and in the both cases backslashes cause syntax error.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: I think the backslashes are there to prevent csh from doing history expansion on the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 2):

As described by *Hauke* the intention here is to only have unique elements in the `$PATH` variable.

This is not a portable awk script though, `RS` is often restricted to only a single character and not a regular expression. A more portable alternative would be something like this:

```
setenv PATH `printf "%s" "$PATH" | awk '{ sub("/$","") }; x[$0]++ < 1' RS=: | paste -s -d : -`
```

Tested in tcsh with gawk and nawk.

A few things to note:

- the extraneous newline is avoided by using `printf`.
- the `!`, which means history expansion to tcsh, can be replaced by checking if the value is less than 1.
- terminating path separators are removed with `sub()`.

Comment: With `tcsh`, you can do `set -f path=($path)` though (`f` for _first_).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: That is indeed a much better choice, I didn't know about that option. Thanks.